# Add CD drive or dvd driver path to FileName property

Tags: c#, winforms

I had my code to check for installation program on pc and I had window for user to setup this program if it did not setup in his PC. I add my code and it worked well but I want to add cd drive or dvd driver as a path to filename property as I will make autorun CD for more user and these user of course have different cd drive names. So please how can I do that?

note: that I named my cd with Adobe

```
private void OK_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process myProcess = new Process();
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Cd driver path";
    myProcess.Start();
}
```

Comment: If they have more then one cd drive, what you're gonna do? Write some code to iterate over the Drives collection (Drives[] = Drives.GetDrives()) and check what medium they contain. If one contains your installation disc you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect the CD/DVD-drive.

See http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1575.htm on how to query WMI for available devices.

I have made a program that does this every 20 seconds running on over 400 computers for over a year, so I can recommend using this technique (it is stable).